# Accessing page object elements dynamically

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating my first page object model test. Based on [Selenium's test design considerations](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp) I would like to verify that certain elements are found when a page object is instantiated.

> There is one, single, verification which can, and should, be within the page object and that is to verify that the page, **and possibly critical elements on the page**, were loaded correctly.

Is there any way to solve this without resorting to reflection?

```
public class PageObject
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "q")]
    private IWebElement q1 { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "qq")]
    private IWebElement q2 { get; set; }

    protected IWebDriver webDriver;

    public PageObject(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;

        PageFactory.InitElements(webDriver, this);
        HighPriorityElementsFound();
    }

    private bool HighPriorityElementsFound()
    {
        // how to verify all private IWebElements elements here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the constructor to verify that I'm on the right page and I do this by identifying a portion of the URL (URL contains "payments.asp" for the payments page) and some element that is unique to only this particular page vs other pages on the site. If that element doesn't exist, then I throw an exception with a message and log the URL that I'm currently on. This helps because it lets you know immediately that you are not on the page you expected to land on or the page didn't load properly.

Another note... there's no need for `HighPriorityElementsFound()`. You are only going to call that code from the constructor so why not just put that code inside the constructor?

Comment: Basically you're stating what I'm trying to accomplish but I'm afraid it doesn't answer the question. I'm trying to extract `some element that is unique to only this particular page` dynamically instead of hard coded. Not sure what you mean by your last sentence. I'm calling `HighPriorityElementsFound` from the constructor. If it's a method or not is irrelevant.

Comment: How would your script be able to identify an element that is unique vs all the other pages on the site that it has never visited? On the second point, functions are for reusable code. `HighPriorityElementsFound()` will never be reused so why put it in a function? Also, it returns a `bool` but you aren't capturing the return so why bother returning a `bool`?